# Tap to click on Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, 18.10, tap-to-click

I'm enjoying Lubuntu 18.10 so far, but there is only one thing that I don't like. I can't tap the touchpad to click something. Is there any way that I can enable this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this same problem on my System76 laptop. There is no setting control to turn this on and off. The only solution I found was to install Lubuntu 18.04 LTS instead.